# Manage my device group on Firebase Cloud Messaging

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am currently working on an app where I'm testing Firebase messaging for notifications. Since my users can have multiple devices, I used device group.

To create my device group, I used the user id as a name which works, but I get stuck and limited by the fact that i have no way of managing my devices groups.

The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/device-group) explains that a device group is deleted when it's empty. But right now, I actually have a device group associated to my user and it contains my current token, but also old ones created when I was doing some experimentation (I didn't register them at the time since I was testing).

Right now, my mac receives 6 notifications when I send a request to that device group and I can't reset/delete or recover the old tokens to delete them.

So this device group is lost and I can't use it anymore, since I can't clean it?

Or there's a way to clean all the previous token from a device, clean/delete a device group or get all the token from a device group in order to remove them?

Comment: Have you tried following what was mentioned in the *Adding and removing devices from a device group* section? Sending a post towards `https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/notification` with the `operation` equal to `remove`.

Comment: This isn't documented at all it seems but I managed to to perform a `GET` here: `https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/notification?notification_key_name=your-key-name`. That should give you the device list. From there you could remove the keys with the POST as described by @AL

Comment: AL: remove needs an array of the registration_ids and i didn't saved them so i can't remove them from the device group.

G0dsquad: this request send me back my notification_key for the group device but no list of ids :/

Comment: Just noticed that. I thought it returned the list but it just seems to give you a new key!

Comment: That is a problem. I suggest contacting Firebase Support, see if they can do something from their end. The way I see it, the only possible way you can manage them is blocked because the necessary registration ids are not available. Are you also not seeing any canonical ids from the response?

Comment: No, i don't. The device group just send back his notification_key. And if i try to use the last notification_token i get for my mac, the canonical_id is equal 0.